# How to map dictionary keys to list of column names in Python Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm new to Pandas Dataframe.

I've a requirement of persisting the incoming `JSON` into `MySQL` database.

Column at database:

```sql
    column1 -- maps to key1
    column2 -- maps to key2
    column3 -- maps to key3
```

Incoming `JSON`: `payload`

```java
    {
       "key1" : "value11",
       "key2" : "value12",
       "key3" : "value13",
    },
     
     {
       "key1" : "value21",
       "key2" : "value22",
       "key3" : "value23",
    }
```

The `JSON` translates to `dictionary` in python. So, if I do:

```py
from panadas import DataFrame

df = DataFrame(data=list(payload))
print(df)
```

**Output:**

**Key1    Key2    key3**

value11 value12 value13
value21 value22 value23

But, I want an output as (inserted into db):

**Column1   Column2   Column3**

value11   value12   value13
value21  value22    value23

I know this can be done using:

```py
# values = list of values from each dictionary in payload
# col_name_list = ['Column1', 'Column3', 'Column3']
df = DataFrame(data=values, columns=col_name_list)
```

But, how do I make sure that the mapping, i.e., `Column1 -> Key1` holds. Using the approach, if the order of keys in payload changes, there can be a situation where I will end up inserting `key1`'s value into `column2`.

So, can I pass some sort of `map` of dict keys to column names that `DataFrame` can refer before picking values for the columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually turn your JSON input into a pandas Dataframe as is if it is a list of dictionaries and then create a custom map to simply rename the column names.

```
my_map = {"key1": "column1", "key2": "column2", "key3": "column3"}


data = [{
       "key1" : "value11",
       "key2" : "value12",
       "key3" : "value13",
    },
     
     {
       "key1" : "value21",
       "key2" : "value22",
       "key3" : "value23",
    }]
        

df = pd.DataFrame(data).rename(columns=my_map)
print(df)
```

Output:

> ```
>    column1  column2  column3
> 0  value11  value12  value13
> 1  value21  value22  value23
> ```

EDIT to show that it works if the order of keys changes

```
my_map = {"key1": "column1", "key2": "column2", "key3": "column3"}


data = [{
       "key2" : "value12",
       "key1" : "value11",
       "key3" : "value13",
    },

     {
       "key3" : "value23",
       "key2" : "value22",
       "key1" : "value21",
    }]


df = pd.DataFrame(data).rename(columns=my_map)
print(df)
```

Output:

> ```
>    column1  column2  column3
> 0  value11  value12  value13
> 1  value21  value22  value23
> ```